# Why does SSIS take Significantly Longer to Import 8500 Records than Manually Importing via SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an Excel file that has 8 sheets.  None of them are particularly large, the entire file is less than 2MB.  The sheet I am trying to import has 8500 records with about 70 columns.
If I use Task->Import Data from the Database in SSMS it takes about 1 minute to import.
I created a SSIS package that refreshed a bunch of tables/files and recreates the sheet I am trying to import.  It then creates the table (no index), and then I have a data flow task that imports the data.  When I run the import task in SSIS it took 10min to complete.

Couple things to note.
I have been using this package for about a year.  I have had all kinds of problems with the connection manager, but I have been able to get it up and running again and it took like 10s to import the records (prob 8s to open the Excel file, and 2s to import).
I had issues again with the connection manager just before this.  I was getting the error `AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009`  I deleted the connection manager and recreated using Excel 2016 (I use Office 365) and it still didn't work.  I tried again with Excel 2007-2010 and it works, but it's slow as hell.

For good measure I checked to ensure that `Run64bitRuntime` is set to `FALSE`
My CPU never reached double digits and my memory was 20-26%.

Other questions I found were quite old, and most were trying to run remotely.  The SQL Server is Azure cloud, but everything else is on my local PC.

SQL Server 12.0.2 and Visual Studio 2019 (w/ SSIS and SSDT)

[image: Destination Setup]

Comment: In the Data Flow, how do you have the destination component configured? Screenshot is helpful in this situation

Comment: @billinkc I don't know why the destination would be the issue when the error is reading the Excel file, but it IS Microsoft so who know.  I added a screenshot, is that what you needed?

Comment: @Dizzy49 Is it really necessary to bring all these 70 columns in? Maybe you should uncheck some columns not to bring some suspicious columns(big size etc.. ) inside and test the package again.

Comment: @Dizzy49 the Import Data task uses SSIS too. You can even save the generated package and inspect it. Check what's different between the generated package and yours

Comment: As the answer says, the *destination* matters a *lot*. That's where all the settings that affect the import operation are configured. If you read the actual error message it says `"Invalid character value for cast specification".`. The wizard will detect type changes between the source and target and add conversion steps based on your settings. Your own flow has no conversions

Answer (score 4):

The difference in load speed is due to the choice of "Data access mode." The package that is built via SSMS uses "Table or View-Fast Load" whereas you've selected "Table or View"

The difference in implementation is the Table or View is basically single insert statements, like a Pez dispenser. If you want to get just a bit of data added to a table, Table or View is right for you.

If you have a lots of data, then the Fast Load option is likely what you want as you'll finish much sooner. Fast Load sends data in batches, which is a configuration option, and pours that data into the destination table. Downside to this approach is that if the destination table is very busy with lots of other processes querying and updating it, Fast Load can block them until it has pushed all of its data to the destination.

As you're working with Excel, I suspect even if you're loading a million rows, the time it has the table locked is going to be inconsequential unless your SQL Server is just pathetically under-resourced.

And as [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) wisely pointed out, another opportunity for the slower performance is failing data type conversions. Excel is pulling in data, mostly likely as Unicode on every column. If you're landing that into a well defined table, there is an implicit conversion from DT_WSTR/Unicode data types to not-that. And that is not a native functionality for an SSIS package. You'll need to use an explicit conversion from the source data type to the target. Choices here are Derived Column (my preference) or the Data Type Conversion component. I favor Derived Columns as I find I have to massage the data to before a native conversion will work so if I have to futz with the values, I might as well handle the conversion as well.

Comment: The error is a type conversion error. I suspect the delay is caused by conversion errors on multiple if not all rows.

Comment: Interesting.  I manually imported the table, and almost everything is varchar, there are a few decimal fields.  I copied the table definition and use that to recreate the table when the ssis package is run.  Sadly, I do need all 70 columns.  I'm part of this process cuts down from the over 700 (yes SEVEN HUNDRED) fields to the 70 I actually need.

Comment: I think I changed the Data Access Mode when I was trying to get the connection to work again.  I changed it back, looks like max insert commit size is "2147483647".  Is that too high?  It would be nice if Excel or SSIS would say which field/columns it had issues with.  It's probably the decimals, I swear they always get screwed in in Excel.  I do quite a bit of transformation using Power Query when I combine everything.  Some of the numbers are stored as a string with numbers, so 123.05 is just 12305, or 1.2305 is also stored as 12305, so figuring all that out is fun.

Comment: Excel: an excellent data visualization tool. Also Excel: the worst data transport format.